# Property "open" was accessed during render but is not defined on instance

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuejs3, alpine.js

Inside my Laravel-Vue app this

Works:

```
@include('header')

<div id="app">
    @yield('content')
</div>

@include('footer')
```

But putting **@includes** inside #app, throws warning "Property "open" was accessed during render but is not defined on instance."

Not working:

```
<div id="app">
    @include('header')
    @yield('content')
    @include('footer')
</div>
```

**header.blade.php**

```
<header x-data="{ open: false }">
    <button @click="open = !open"> open </button>
    <nav :class="{'hidden' : !open}" x-cloak></nav>
</header>
```

Answer (score 3):

The reason was I put Alpine.js inisde Vue, so `@click` and `:class` weren't working.

So I replaced them with `x-bind:class` and `x-on:click` and everything worked as expected.